# pseudo elements in htmlpurifier (with csstidy)

Tags: pseudo-element, htmlpurifier

[HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is awesome, but there are feature that unfortunately implemented only half. One of them is parsing of pseudo elements/classes.

Filter/ExtractStyleBlocks.php have only this pseudo elements:

```
$this->_class_attrdef = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_CSS_Ident();
$this->_enum_attrdef = new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(
    array(
        'first-child',
        'link',
        'visited',
        'active',
        'hover',
        'focus'
    )
);
```

Its have ":first-child", but not ":last-child" and missing much more entries. I can inserting itself, but there are pseudo elements like ":nth-child(n)" or ":nth-last-of-type(n)" which have a value (possible values: "2", "odd", "even", "2n+1"). Can anyone tell me how I can modify the source here, for insert pseudo elements with a value?